# MS Teams for Android: can't send an image to bot

Tags: c#, android, mobile, chatbot, microsoft-teams

MS Teams for Iphone has an option to send an image to the bot, but MS Teams for Android doesn't.
Maybe there is a way to do this on Android too? (I mean only inline images, not attaches) 
Is this a bug?
Tested on the latest versions of MS Teams for Iphone and Android.

Answer (score 0):

@John Walker Sending and receiving files to bots on mobile devices is not supported as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=dotnet#using-the-teams-bot-apis).